# Javamail linebreaks cannot be saved into database

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am using javamail to read mailbox and saving all the incoming mail into sql database of my application. My problem is when the mail is in String format the line breaks are not saving into db. For example the mail I am reading (that is seen in log) is like below

```
Hello

This is a test mail

Regards

Sender
```

But in database column it is saving as a continued line as-

```
Hello This is a test mail Regards Sender
```

I am using following code for above task

```
if(content instanceof String){
  String body = (String)content;

  inBox.setMailContent(body);

  inBoxDAO.save(inBox);
}
```

I have not used mail stuff before, any suggestion will be helpful. Note this is working perfectly with multipart html format. Problem is in the case where the sender's mail is coming as plain text

Comment: The html probably doesn't have any newlines.  I don't think the problem is with the mail portion; it's probably related to how you're storing and retrieving the data in the database.

Answer (score -1):

You can use \n for new lines. you might have to unescape the string you get from the DB. The Apache Commons Lang have a method for that:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeJava%28java.io.Writer,%20java.lang.String%29

- it will turn a sequence of '\' and 'n' into a newline character, unless the '\' is preceded by another '\'.

So you would have simply to call

```
String content = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(rs.getString("content"));
```

Comment: Why would the data contain a sequence of '\' and 'n'?